# Error: com.google.firebase.FirebaseException: No AppCheckProvider installed

Tags: firebase, flutter

i need to delete a file from firebase storage, i am following this code:

```
  static deleteFile(String urlFile) async {
try {
  final ref = FirebaseStorage.instance.refFromURL(urlFile);
  await ref.delete();
} catch (e) {
  if (kDebugMode) {
    print(e.toString());
  }
}
```

}

the file is deleted, but the console displays this error:

> W/StorageUtil(13434): Error getting App Check token; using placeholder token instead. Error: com.google.firebase.FirebaseException: No AppCheckProvider installed.

the user is successfully authenticated.

Comment: Have you figure this out? got Play integrity installed but still got this error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

usually this is  a network connection problem

Answer (score 1):

App Check Attestation Providers:
For IOS: DeviceCheck or App Attest &
For Android: Play Integrity or SafetyNet

Use Anyone of these you like, I personally use SafetyNet for my android apps.

1. Add this inside apps/build.gradle:

> dependencies {
> implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appcheck-safetynet:16.0.0'
> }

2. Then Initialize App Check Add this:

> FirebaseApp.initializeApp(/*context=*/ this);
> FirebaseAppCheck firebaseAppCheck = FirebaseAppCheck.getInstance();
> firebaseAppCheck.installAppCheckProviderFactory(
> SafetyNetAppCheckProviderFactory.getInstance());

I hope it fix your error. for more you can follow official doc: [https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check/android/safetynet-provider].

---

Another Temporary fix... for TP & Practice Apps

*Simply Remove If Condition from your firebase storage/db/auth rules*

> rules_version = '2';
> service firebase.storage {
> match /b/{bucket}/o {
> match /{allPaths=**} {
> allow read, write: if false;
> }
> }
> }

Comment: SafetyNet is deprecated and cannot be used anymore on new projects